# Trying to run "npm install ably" but having trouble

Tags: node.js, npm

I am starting out with java and raspberry pi.  I just want to get rolling with node.js, and install some packages for the pi's pins, and also want ably.  My first project is just to breadboard up an LED and make it blink.  I have set up my pi correctly, opened a terminal and typed:

`$ sudo apt update`

`$ sudo apt full-upgrade`

these worked find.  I then typed:

`$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash –`

This worked fine.

Then I typed:
`$ sudo apt install nodejs`

This worked fine.

I then made a project directory:

`pi@raspi:~$ mkdir nodeLED`

`pi@raspi:~$ cd nodeLED`

I then created my package.json file:
 then tried to install the onoff package
`pi@raspi:~/nodeLED $ npm init -y`

I got the correct information writing to the json file.  So I now wanted to just `install npm onoff` and `npm ably`.

`pi@raspi:~/nodeLED $ npm install onoff`
this seems to have worked fine, as I see the onoff folder within my nodeLED folder.
HOWEVER, and here is my big question, when I write:
`pi@raspi:~/nodeLED $ npm install ably`

```
    I just get a [................] / fetchMetadata: 
sill resolveWithNewModule ably@1.0.14 checking installable status
```

And it just sits at this line forever.
Can anyone help me on why I just can't install the ably package?
Thanks
Tad

Answer (score 0):

maybe its related to your npm's cache so try this before

`npm cache clean --force`

then

`npm install ably`

Comment: I ran the code you provided, and I still get the following after running npm install ably               [................] / fetchMetadata: 
sill resolveWithNewModule ably@1.0.14 checking installable status